# static variable value

Tags: c#, variables, static

I have a static variable declared in my class as :

```
private static DirectoryInfo _extractionFolder;
```

in some function i change this to :

```
_extractionFolder = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\TEST");
```

then on same function on few lines down can I change this variable again?

I am trying it and it doesn't seems to change.or is it me having a rough day.

Comment: You can do that, although it isn't the best design. Post your code so we can figure out the problem.

Comment: _extraction folder is of type DirectoryInfo not a string. Might that be your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > or is it me having a rough day?

Rough day I think :) You should be able to set its value like any other variable.

Comment: It happens to the best of us :)

Answer (score 2):

That code wouldn't even compile - you're trying to assign a *string* value to a `DirectoryInfo` variable.

I suspect what's happened is that you've actually declared a *local* variable which is hiding the string variable, like this:

```
private static DirectoryInfo _extractionFolder;

public void Foo()
{
    string _extractionFolder;
    ...
    _extractionFolder = @"C:\TEST"; // Modifies local variable, not static one
}
```

Mutable static variables are rarely a good idea though, and access to them needs to be handled carefully due to threading concerns.

Comment: @Sam1: Please take this as a lesson in why it's important to provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, when you submit a question. In this case, I suspect that in coming up with that short but complete program, you'd have solved your problem.

Comment: Hi, I know but I assumed the problem was with static variable hence asking if it is possible to change the value twice...anyway thanks for advice :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as static variables go, you should be able to change it.  There must be something wrong with what you're setting it to or how you're using the variable once you've set it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean

```
_extractionFolder = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\TEST");
```

Then you can access its properties and later after doing another 'new' you can get information for a different directory. Is that what you are attempting to do?